# Does Elementary OS support HPLIP for HP printers?

Tags: printer, hp

I just learned of Elementary OS. I might like to try it.  Does Elementary OS work with HPLIP drivers for HP printers? If I use Elementary OS, I must have compatibility with my networked HP Officejet Pro 8500 All-in-one printer.

Answer (score 3):

You can install the package `hplip` via the command line in a terminal:

```
 sudo apt install hplip
```

Comment: On my system (fully updated Loki) this command crashes with:
Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 hplip : Зависит: cups (>= 1.1.20)
         Зависит: printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.16.3+repack0-1) но он не будет установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
(it's about insoluble dependences)

Answer (score 1):

I use HP  Officejet and in my case I just plugged the printer and clicked print - It worked without installing any software. :)